# How to keep The structure of an array as it is while Boolean mask in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

I already Search too many post regarding Boolean masking but never found a clear description So Posting a new Questions.

I have Tried

```
import numpy as np

#create numpy array
np_arr=np.array([[1,23,22],[54,28,45],[36,74,85],[25,26,98]])
print("Normal Numpy Array:\n",np_arr)

#Create boolean mask (no grator than 36)
mask=np_arr>36

#print mask value
print("\nBoolean Mask:\n",mask)

#apply mask on numpy array
apply_mask=np_arr[mask]
print("\nNumpy array  Apply Mask:\n",apply_mask)
```

This Give Output

```
Normal Numpy Array:
 [[ 1 23 22]
 [54 28 45]
 [36 74 85]
 [25 26 98]]
(4, 3)

Boolean Mask:
 [[False False False]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True  True]
 [False False  True]]

Numpy array  Apply Mask:
 [54 45 74 85 98]
```

But I Expect

```
Normal Numpy Array:
 [[ 1 23 22]
 [54 28 45]
 [36 74 85]
 [25 26 98]]


Boolean Mask:
 [
 [ True  True]
 [True  True]
 [True]
 ]

Numpy array  Apply Mask:
[
 [54 45]
 [74 85]
 [98]
 ]
```

I want to Keep the Result structure same as above

i have tried **np.where** but i need to solve it using with the help of **Boolean mask**

```
np.where(np_arr,np_arr,0)
#This will add 0 to numpy array
```

Comment: Would this suffice? `np_arr*(mask*1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [152]: arr =np.array([[1,23,22],[54,28,45],[36,74,85],[25,26,98]])           
In [153]: mask= arr>36                                                          
In [154]: arr                                                                   
Out[154]: 
array([[ 1, 23, 22],
       [54, 28, 45],
       [36, 74, 85],
       [25, 26, 98]])
In [155]: mask                                                                  
Out[155]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True]])
In [156]: arr[mask]                                                             
Out[156]: array([54, 45, 74, 85, 98])
```

Looks like you want a row by row mask:

```
In [157]: [a[m] for a,m in zip(arr,mask)]                                       
Out[157]: [array([], dtype=int64), array([54, 45]), array([74, 85]), array([98])]
```

When the desired output is arrays or lists of differing lengths, it's a good indication that some sort of iteration is required.  The 'whole-array' operations return an array - 1d, 2d, etc, not a list of arrays.

Sometimes it's handy to create a masked array:

```
In [161]: np.ma.MaskedArray(data=arr, mask=~mask)                               
Out[161]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[--, --, --],
        [54, --, 45],
        [--, 74, 85],
        [--, --, 98]],
  mask=[[ True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

`nonzero` (alias `where`) can produce an indexing tuple that the selects the same elements:

```
In [164]: np.nonzero(mask)                                                      
Out[164]: (array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3]), array([0, 2, 1, 2, 2]))
In [165]: arr[_]                                                                
Out[165]: array([54, 45, 74, 85, 98])
```

but it doesn't obviously help with creating the row list.  Well, you could do some sort of grouping on the first index array.

That tuple gives an idea of how the boolean masking is done.  It selects 5 elements, defined by the pairs (1,0),(1,2),(2,1) etc.

You could use `where` or the mask to set the False values to 0:

```
In [166]: np.where(mask, arr, 0)                                                
Out[166]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [54,  0, 45],
       [ 0, 74, 85],
       [ 0,  0, 98]])
In [167]: arr*mask.astype(int)                                                  
Out[167]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [54,  0, 45],
       [ 0, 74, 85],
       [ 0,  0, 98]])
```

But that's different from your list of lists.